# How do I find out what application is trying to wake my MBP?

Tags: sleep-wake

my mac book pro is refusing to stay asleep. I noticed it will wake up roughly every thirty minutes and display the screensaver password screen and even when the lid is closed I will be able to hear it wake and then go back to sleep quite regularly. I installed please sleep but that didn't fix it either. another curious thing I noticed was that sometimes when waking the mbp from sleep it will not let me type anything into the username/password fields. only closing the lid and reopening it after a few seconds will fix this.

I'm running 10.6.7 on a 17" 2.66ghz mbp i7 with 8gb ram.

my question is this: how do I find out which app is trying to constantly wake up my system? (wake for networks access is disabled.)

Answer (score 2):

Macs will wake up in response to many hardware events. Changing a USB/Firewire/Thunderbolt cable or even plugging in / powering on a connected device will wake Macs that are sleeping. Keyboard presses, clamshell sensor detecting an open of the display lid will also wake up a sleeping Mac. These are pretty well known and obvious, even if you don't realize a pet or power fluctuation can cause a wake event.

Two software items will also wake a sleeping mac and both rely on the power management / system management controller. Both are seen in the Energy Saver preference pane. This is how applications can do the same thing as hardware and wake your mac.

[image]

For macs with a battery - the power adapter needs to be connected and powered for much of this to work. The **Wake for network access** is both the [standard WakeOnLan (WOL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) as well as [Apple's Bonjour Sleep Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Sleep_Proxy_Service_%28Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy%29). I like the article [About Wake on Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774) that explains how Apple has extended the concept of WOL and made a service.

If you disable these two items - software can no longer wake your sleeping mac and you can know if it's a hardware event or a software event. The other answers go into how to look at the logs to know which event has made a specific wake up request. Hopefully this helps frame the bigger picture of how your mac can take a cat nap with one eye open.

Comment: It's most likely wake-on-LAN. I had the same problem on my old MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have /Application/Utilities/Console.app running and when you MBP awakes, check the logs. It will normally log a reason for wakeup, e.g.

```
06/08/2011 13:42:39.000 kernel: Wake reason: EHC1
06/08/2011 13:42:39.000 kernel: The USB device HubDevice (Port 1 of Hub at 0xfd000000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (2)
06/08/2011 13:42:39.000 kernel: The USB device Keyboard Hub (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd100000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (3)
06/08/2011 13:42:39.000 kernel: The USB device Apple Keyboard> (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd120000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (3)
```

Comment: I followed your advice but all I get is console telling me it got sleep and wake notices from the system. it looks like this:   09.08.11 07:49:51 PleaseSleep[172] Sleep notification received from the system 09.08.11 08:31:02 PleaseSleep[172] Wake notification received from the system

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need further info to proceed. Have you checked the console log for status messages? Also, do you have any peripherals/USB hardware items attached? If so, reboot without them and see if the problem persists.